# PHP Form, If Statements

Tags: php

Looking for any help, I'm very new to coding and am struggling big time.  I am trying to write a program that asks a user to enter a 10 digit ISBN.  I need to check that its all numbers and is ten digits.  then I need to make sure its a valid ISBN by multiplying each digit by its position from the end, getting the total of all and dividing by 11.  I am trying to do it step by step, i.e. enter an instruction, test, enter next, test, etc. as I was told when learning that's the best way.  I haven't gotten as far as the mathematical test of the array cause I have no clue how to go about that, but also, even if I enter ten digits I'm being prompted to to enter exactly ten.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Enter a ten digit number</h4>
        <?php
            if(empty($_POST['isbn'])){
                echo "Please enter a ten digit number";
            } elseif (strlen($_POST['submit'] !==10)){
                echo "Please enter exactly ten digits";
            } else {
                echo "You have entered the correct number of digits";
                $array = str_split($_POST['submit']);
            }
        ?>
        <form action="Qu2.php" method="post">
        ISBN: <input type="number" name="isbn">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your input name is `isbn`, not `submit`. You need to close the `strlen`. ISBNs also are hyphenated usually so you probably want 10-13 characters.

Comment: `elseif (strlen($_POST['submit'] !==10)` you're using the wrong array here. Check on the isbn, not the submit.

Comment: and splitting on the wrong array there also

Comment: also be warned that isbn can have an X as last "digit" not only numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all characters in a string are numerical using [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php).

To check if the given string is valid ISBN-10 you can use the following function.

```
function isIsbn10($isbn) {
    $check = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ loops through all numbers in the "ISBN" 
        $check += (int)$isbn[$i] * (10 - $i);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ multiplies the number with the position from the last character
    }

    return (0 === ($check % 11)) ? true : false;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ checks if total is divisible by 11 
}

var_dump(isIsbn10("0198526636")); // bool(true)
```

Your code will look like this (fixed some mistakes that were in your code):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['isbn'])){
        echo "Please enter a ten digit number";
    } elseif (strlen($_POST['isbn']) !== 10) {
        echo "Please enter exactly ten digits";
    } elseif (!ctype_digit($_POST['isbn'])) {
        echo "You have nonnumerical characters in your ISBN!";
    } elseif (!isIsbn10($_POST['isbn'])) {
        echo "ISBN is invalid!";
    } else {
        echo "ISBN is VALID!";
    }
}
```